Swapping tokens from pancakeswap
I am having trouble executing the swap on PancakeSwap. I always encounter this error. Can someone please check my buy function and tell me if anything is missing?
ERROR - Unexpected error during token purchase: 
Could not identify the intended function with name swapExactETHForTokens, positional arguments with type(s) (int,address,address,address,int) and keyword arguments with type(s) {}.
Found 1 function(s) with the name swapExactETHForTokens: ['swapExactETHForTokens(address,uint256,uint256,address[],address,uint256)']
Function invocation failed due to improper number of arguments.

def buy_token(token_address, amount_in_bnb, gas_price_gwei):
try:
    # Validate that the WBNB amount is greater than 0
    if Decimal(amount_in_bnb) <= 0:
        raise ValueError(f"Invalid WBNB amount: {amount_in_bnb}")
    
    # Fetch and log the current BNB balance of the wallet
    balance = web3.eth.get_balance(WALLET_ADDRESS)
    balance_in_bnb = Web3.from_wei(balance, 'ether')
    logging.info(f"Current BNB Balance: {balance_in_bnb} BNB")

    # Check if the balance is sufficient to proceed with the transaction
    if balance_in_bnb < Decimal(amount_in_bnb):
        raise ValueError(f"Insufficient BNB balance to proceed with the transaction")

    # Convert BNB amount to Wei for the transaction
    amount_in_wei = Web3.to_wei(Decimal(amount_in_bnb), 'ether')
    
    # Ensure the token address is in checksum format
    token_to_buy_address = Web3.to_checksum_address(token_address)

    # Define the swap path: WBNB -> Token
    path = [Web3.to_checksum_address(WBNB_ADDRESS), token_to_buy_address]

    # Get the expected output token amount from PancakeSwap for the input WBNB amount
    amounts_out = router.functions.getAmountsOut(amount_in_wei, path).call()
    amount_out_min = int(amounts_out[1] * (1 - SLIPPAGE))  # Apply slippage tolerance (e.g., 0.5%)
    logging.info(f"Expected token amount with slippage: {amount_out_min}")

    # Set up PancakeSwap Router contract
    pancakeswap_contract = web3.eth.contract(address=PANCAKESWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS, abi=ROUTER_ABI)

    # Adjust gas price to Gwei and convert it to Wei
    adjusted_gas_price = Web3.to_wei(gas_price_gwei, 'gwei')

    # Fetch the current nonce for the wallet address to avoid transaction conflicts
    nonce = web3.eth.get_transaction_count(WALLET_ADDRESS)

    # Set a deadline for the transaction (current time + 10 minutes)
    deadline = int(time.time()) + 600  # 10 minutes from now

    # Log transaction details for review
    logging.info(f"Building transaction: amount_out_min={amount_out_min}, path={path}, to={WALLET_ADDRESS}, deadline={deadline}, gasPrice={adjusted_gas_price}")

    # Build the transaction using the correct function signature for PancakeSwap's Router contract
    txn = pancakeswap_contract.functions.swapExactETHForTokens(
        amount_out_min,  # Minimum amount of tokens to receive after slippage
        path,            # Swap path: [WBNB, token]
        WALLET_ADDRESS,  # Address to receive tokens
        deadline         # Transaction deadline (Unix timestamp)
    ).build_transaction({
        'from': WALLET_ADDRESS,
        'value': amount_in_wei,     # Amount of WBNB to swap
        'gas': 300000,              # Gas limit (adjustable if necessary)
        'gasPrice': adjusted_gas_price,  # Gas price in Wei
        'nonce': nonce,             # Current nonce
    })

    # Sign the transaction using the wallet's private key
    signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(txn, private_key=PRIVATE_KEY)

    # Send the signed transaction and get the transaction hash
    tx_hash = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
    logging.info(f"Transaction hash: {web3.to_hex(tx_hash)}")
    
    return web3.to_hex(tx_hash)

except ValueError as ve:
    # Log any value errors such as invalid BNB amount or insufficient balance
    logging.error(f"Value Error during token purchase: {ve}")
    return None
except Exception as e:
    # Log unexpected errors during the process
    logging.error(f"Unexpected error during token purchase: {e}")
    return None


You have either used a wrong ABI or passed in arguments incorrectly. It says in your ABI, there is a function:
['swapExactETHForTokens(address,uint256,uint256,address[],address,uint256)']

However you have used the signature:
(int,address,address,address,int)

Note: It's most likely that you have used a wrong ABI since your function call seems to match with pancakeswap signature. I have assumed used pancakeswap address on BSC to verify. Please verify with the actual contract you intented to use.

